# Django user injection in model properties

Tags: django, request, models, django-custom-tags

I have this models in Django:

```
News
Comments
Reactions
```

Relations are:

```
a News has various Comments
a Comment has various Reactions
```

The problem is the **user** (in request / session): the user may subscribe to a reaction, or a comment; he may be logged in or not. *(it's a foo example, it doesn't have much sense)*

I can't do in template:

```
{% for reaction in this_news.comments.reactions %}
 {{ reaction.name }}
 {% if reaction.user_subscribed %} #reaction.user_subscribed(request.user)...
 You have subscribed this reaction!
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Problems are:

- I can't call the method in the template with a parameter (see the comment above)
- Models don't have access to request

Now i'm calling an `init_user` method in `News` Model, passing the request. Then i have the same method in `Comment` and `Reaction` model, and i have to set the `user_subscribed` property cycling the children of each model.

Isn't there a smarter way to do this?

**EDIT**: thanks to the Ignacio's hint about using custom tag i'm trying to do a generic mode to pass the user (avoiding the use of closures because i don't know how to use them atm):

```
def inject_user(parser, token):
    try:
        # split_contents() knows not to split quoted strings.
        tag_name, method_injected, user = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires exactly three arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    return InjectUserNode(method_injected, user)

class InjectUserNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, method_injected, user):
        self.method_injected = template.Variable(method_injected)
        self.user = template.Variable(user)

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            method_injected = self.method_injected.resolve(context)
            user = self.user.resolve(context)
            return method_injected(user)
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            return ''
```

When i use it `{% inject_user object.method_that_receives_a_user request.user %}` i come to this error `'str' object is not callable` in `method_injected(user)`; how i can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved it in a less elegant way, but it worked for me.

I've created a sort of singleton in my `User` defined class, with a property that i set in every view i need it.

The property is `User.current`.

Then, inside the models, where i need that i get the current user looking in `User.current`.

Answer (score 1):

Write [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that take the user and set a context variable to indicate presence or absence of the criterion.

Comment: it doesn't involve only user_subscribed property, there many behaviours driven by user.. is there a generic way to do this?
with the custom tag i can take a model method in template and pass it the user?

Comment: can u explain me or point me on how to do this? documentation is not clear on your last sentence (closures to generate the tags)

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271-these-nasty-closures-caveats-for-the-closure-enthu/